# SSL Certificate on Tomcat - Alias name(tomcat) does not identify a key

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat, alias, keytool

I am working with an SSL certificate in Apache tomcat. I have created CSR and got a JKS file. Then when I have given the CSR to certificate authority, then they have given me the certificate. When I have tested the JKS certificate using the following command,

```
keytool -list -keystore ava_bankasia-bd_com.jks
```

I have got the following output:

```
Keystore type: PKCS12
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

tomcat, Jun 22, 2021, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): 7F:F3:C5:60:D1:E6:E5:04:2A:E8:2E:D1:D7:1A:92:DE:39:47:75:BD:06:25:0D:D0:CB:C0:55:BA:D6:2B:28:E9
```

Then I have configured the tomcat with the following code:

```
<Connector port="443" 
           protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
           SSLEnabled="true" 
           maxThreads="150" 
           scheme="https" 
           secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" 
           sslProtocol="TLS"
           keystoreFile="/u01/csr_certificate/ava_bankasia-bd_com.jks"  
           keystorePass="-------"
           keyAlias="tomcat" />
```

I have imported them all into the Keystore ok (but obviously not!) but the error I'm getting from Tomcat is: 'java.io.IOException Alias name does not identify a key entry. The full error is as follows:

```
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:1076)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:552)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:846)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:639)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:662)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:302)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:472)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Alias name [tomcat] does not identify a key entry
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:100)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:72)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:247)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1143)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.init(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:222)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:599)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:80)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:1074)
        ... 13 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Alias name [tomcat] does not identify a key entry
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getKeyManagers(SSLUtilBase.java:336)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.createSSLContext(SSLUtilBase.java:245)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:98)
        ... 20 more
```

Any ideas? This is the first time I've done this so maybe I've messed up something blindingly obvious?

The site works fine on port 80.

Would LOVE to hear some suggestions :)

Comment: _"Alias name [tomcat] does not identify a **key** entry"_: it's a **certificate** entry. You must find the private key used to generate the CSR (probably it's in a keystore) and add the certificate to that key.

Comment: I have imported the certificate using the keyttol command

Comment: You imported the certificate into a **new** keystore, hence creating a `trustedCertEntry`. You need to import it into the keystore that contained your private key (a `privateKeyEntry`).

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Please explain in your question how did you generate your CSR? Do you still have the files you used to generate it? They contain the [private key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography), without it your certificate (basically a signed public key) is worthless.

Comment: I have the CSR files. Should I check the private key in it ?